# Trying to setup Susy grid with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, susy-compass, susy-sass

I want to use [susy](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/) with Rails 4.

I added `gem 'susy'` to my gemfile. Then I run `bundle install`. Everything is fine and says the gem was installed. Now I restart my Rails server, and add `@import "susy";` to application.css.scss (I'm using sprockets).

I get the error `File to import not found or unreadable: susy.` Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [the best of my understanding](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/339), Sass-Rails is still using an older version of Sass that does not support Susy 2. I hope they are working on an update, and have it available soon. In the meantime, you will have to use Susy 1.0. That also means using Compass, and adding `require "susy"` to your `config.rb`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an update for those of you trying to use Compass, Susy 2 and Rails 4.1.
This would probably work with other versions of Rails but I haven't tested. Please note that I've only done preliminary testing and you'll be using a beta version of sass-rails so use at your own risk.

In your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.0.beta1' # This is the important bit since it supports Sass 3.3    
gem 'susy'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```

In your **application.rb**:

```
...
require 'rails/all'
require 'susy'
...
```

In your **stylesheet**:

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'susy';

.container { @include container; }
...
```

Link to issue: https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/339